# Cannot execute java command on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, installed JDK and interestingly have the following error. Why do I have this error though `java` file exist in there?

```
appuser@securexmlgw-db:~/Downloads/jdk1.7.0_04/bin$ ls
appletviewer  javac         jcontrol    jstack        policytool   tnameserv
apt           javadoc       jdb         jstat         rmic         unpack200
ControlPanel  javah         jhat        jstatd        rmid         wsgen
extcheck      javap         jinfo       jvisualvm     rmiregistry  wsimport
idlj          java-rmi.cgi  jmap        keytool       schemagen    xjc
jar           javaws        jps         native2ascii  serialver
jarsigner     jcmd          jrunscript  orbd          servertool
java          jconsole      jsadebugd   pack200       test
appuser@securexmlgw-db:~/Downloads/jdk1.7.0_04/bin$ ./java -version
-bash: ./java: No such file or directory
```

I have given all exectable persission.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1  500  500   5809 Apr 12  2012 jarsigner*
-rwxrwxrwx 1  500  500   5654 Apr 12  2012 java*
-rwxrwxrwx 1  500  500   5805 Apr 12  2012 javac*
-rwxrwxrwx 1  500  500   5809 Apr 12  2012 javadoc*
```

Comment: Because it's not executable.

Comment: No, It is given required permission of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have downloaded a 32-bit JRE and are running it on a 64-bit platform without emulation libraries. Simply download the one matching your platform, instead.

The kernel returns `ENOENT` on `exec` when it cannot find the ELF interpreter the executable specifies.

Comment: To confirm this, compare the outputs of `uname -m` with the information returned by `file java`. It's likely the `uname` output confirms you are 64-bit and the `file` output confirms the file is compiled for 32-bit.

Comment: installation of jdk-6u29-linux-x64.bin has solved the problem. Thnaks.

Comment: @mmc18 now uninstall it again, so you don't screw up the permissions, and install the **Ubuntu openjdk package** instead. So you get automatic security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that you are **not** on a *native* file system, but e.g. a FAT (Windows) filesystem?

If so, execute permissions are *supposed* to not work, as the filesystem does not have proper permission support. This is called `noexec`, and I recommend *not* changing it. Otherwise, you open doors for hackers.

**Use Ubuntu openjdk-7**. It is much better supported than the Oracle version:

**You only get automatic security updates if you use the packaged version.**

One more thing:

## NEVER EVER MAKE JAVA WRITABLE TO USERS

```
 -rwxrwxrwx 1  500  500   5654 Apr 12  2012 java*
```

this says "any user may modify (=hack, virus infect etc.) your java". **DON'T DO THIS.** Keep write permissions under the tightest control possible.

Comment: If that were the problem, he'd be getting either `EACCES` or `EPERM`, not `ENOENT`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 well spotted. Anyway, his installation is badly screwed...

Comment: It is just for testing in order to find why it is not executable. Normally you are right that such permission should not be given. :)

Comment: I have **never ever heard that write permissions would be necessary for execution**, in particular not when there is an execute bit.